# Making async jquery calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.getJSON("https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/sets", function(sets) {
    $(sets).each(function() {
      $('<div id="' + this.name + '" class="set"/>')
      .text(this.name)
      .appendTo("#collection");

    });
  });

  $.getJSON("https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/cards", function(cards) {
    $(cards).each(function(){
      $('<div id="' + this.name + '" class="card"/>')
      .text(this.name)
      .appendTo("#" + this.editions[0].set);

    });
  });

});
```

I was wondering how I might (without using ajax and sticking to the "getJSON" method) make the two calls happen asynchronously.  I can't make anything useful happen with the second jQuery object; I believe that's because of the synchronous nature of the calls.  How can I make them work in order?

Comment: _"was wondering how I might (without using ajax and sticking to the "getJSON" method)"_ `$.getJSON()` uses `jQuery.ajax()`. Not certain what expected result is? What is issue with current `javascript`? Are you trying to call second `$.getJSON()` after first call completes?

Comment: `make the two calls happen asynchronously` - they currently **do** happen asynchronously, did you mean synchronously? or perhaps you need the first to complete before starting the second? (you need to also learn what is synchronous and what is asynchronous I think)

Comment: Yes, I want to call them one at a time.  Expected result is:
first call sets div elements for the second call to store its objects in.
My actual error on console is that '#exampleid is not defined', as if the appendTo method wasn't reading the selector as an id but as a string.  However, the logic of the code still requires the calls to happen one at a time, and I think this could be the entire bug.

Comment: Nest one inside the other.

Comment: as @PHPglue - put the second $.getJSON call at the end (inside still) of the callback of the first

Comment: Inside the Anonymous function, after the last `.appendTo()`, in this case.

Comment: I think this seems to be my answer, but as usual, one answer leads to ten new problems.  Something is inconsistent in my api values and I'll have to run this issue down.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want these to happen in order, then you need to specifically serialize them and using the built-in promises that getJSON() returns is a simple way to do that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/sets").then(function (sets) {
        $(sets).each(function () {
            $('<div id="' + this.name + '" class="set"/>')
                .text(this.name)
                .appendTo("#collection");
        });
    }).then(function () {
        $.getJSON("https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/cards").then(function (cards) {
            $(cards).each(function () {
                $('<div id="' + this.name + '" class="card"/>')
                    .text(this.name)
                    .appendTo("#" + this.editions[0].set);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Or, a little faster (end to end time) would be to launch both requests at the same time and then process the results in order.  Again using jQuery promises to manage this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.when(
        $.getJSON("https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/sets"), 
        $.getJSON("https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/cards")
    ).then(function(r1, r2) {
        // process sets
        var sets = r1[0];
        $(sets).each(function() {
          $('<div id="' + this.name + '" class="set"/>')
          .text(this.name)
          .appendTo("#collection");
        });

        // process cards
        var cards = r2[0];
        $(cards).each(function(){
          $('<div id="' + this.name + '" class="card"/>')
          .text(this.name)
          .appendTo("#" + this.editions[0].set);
        });
    });
});
```

This last scheme uses `$.when()` to tell us when both ajax calls are done and it also sequences the results for us, regardless of which one actually finished first.

Answer (score 0):

To run the getJSONS's in sequence, run the second in the callback of the first

like so

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/sets", function(sets) {
        $(sets).each(function() {
            $('<div id="' + this.name + '" class="set"/>')
                .text(this.name)
                .appendTo("#collection");
        });
        $.getJSON("https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/cards", function(cards) {
            $(cards).each(function() {
                $('<div id="' + this.name + '" class="card"/>')
                    .text(this.name)
                    .appendTo("#" + this.editions[0].set);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

> personally, I would go with @jfriend00's promise method - I was going to add that to this answer, but he answered in the meantime, so, go with that more flexible  method

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**
Since you said you were trying to use call both `getJSON` methods in order, then you can make the second call work after the first by using the `DOMNodeInserted` event

Well maybe a solution would be to use `DOMNodeInserted` event since you are **appending** to `#collection`

so:

```
$("#collection").on('DOMNodeInserted',function(){

    $.getJSON...
});
```

According to [DOCS](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-MutationEvent)

**DOMNodeInserted**

> Fired when a node has been added as a child of another node. This
>   event is dispatched after the insertion has taken place. The target of
>   this event is the node being inserted.

Comment: My append to collection is successful.  Sorry, I don't understand exactly..

Comment: this doesn't have anything to do with the question :p

Comment: @j3ssi3ftw  says: "Yes, I want to call them one at a time. Expected result is: first call sets div elements for the second call to store its objects in. " so if you want to have **div elements** added first  **before** second ajax call then this is a way to do it.. why the down vote ?